# while opening jupyter notebook, it opens visual studio

Tags: jupyter-notebook

When I am trying to open **jupyter notebook**, it is opening a visual studio code page. The notebook is not opening in a browser.

No error is raised

```
dstlab2@dstlab2-Veriton-M200-H81:~$ jupyter notebook
[I 13:27:51.585 NotebookApp] Serving notebooks from local directory: /home/dstlab2
[I 13:27:51.585 NotebookApp] The Jupyter Notebook is running at:
[I 13:27:51.585 NotebookApp] http://localhost:8888/?token=3aa1b0ab0a42d3749a22ab70e1d8a5db0adb456bc8448d5b
[I 13:27:51.585 NotebookApp] Use Control-C to stop this server and shut down all kernels (twice to skip confirmation).
[C 13:27:51.587 NotebookApp] 

    To access the notebook, open this file in a browser:
        file:///run/user/1000/jupyter/nbserver-3899-open.html
    Or copy and paste one of these URLs:
        http://localhost:8888/?token=3aa1b0ab0a42d3749a22ab70e1d8a5db0adb456bc8448d5b
```

can anyone help me to correct the error?

Comment: I am having a similar behavior, jupyter is not openning the notebook boot but another page file:///home/user/.local/share/jupyter/runtime/nbserver-232-open.html

Comment: A temporarily hack may to launch the browser semi-automatically :): `nohup jupyter lab & sleep 5; /mnt/c/Program\ Files\ \(x86\)/SeaMonkey/seamonkey.exe `grep -om1 http.* nohup.out``

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this in Ubuntu...

Create a new blank **html** file (xxxx.html)

Right click and select properties. A window will open with three tabs

Select the tab : **open with**

The default application would be visual studio (in your case)

Select a suitable browser ( under recommended applications) : **firefox/chrome** etc

Select the button :**set as default**

Then on, it will open in the browser you selected.